# drupal commerce ajax refresh cart summary upon select payment method

Tags: rules, commerce

I have implemented a fee option in rules so that when people select a particular payment method, the current fees will apply, but I am now having problem, I tested deactivating all payment except for particular payment "a" and the fees are loaded as I understand it already refresh the cart with the "default selected payment and trigger the rule to insert the fees" but when I activate more then one payment and the default of payment is not payment "a", when I click on the payment method "a", its not reflecting the changes to the summary cart as I know the fees are inserted after that but in the sense of the UI its not acceptable.

is there any hook that we can use to refresh the cart summary everytime a payment method is selected?

help appreciated

thank you!